# How to RESET attribute of xml element using boost::property_tree?

Tags: c++, xml, xml-attribute, boost-propertytree

I have a xml file, I need to modify few attributes in that file.

My xml file is something like below:

```
<ns0:App xmlns:ns0="AppSchema" MyDir1="C:\App\Dir1" MyDir2="C:\App\Dir2"  ..... some other attributes>
    <ns0:Backend DisableBackend="false">
        <ns0:Logging EnableLogging="false" LogPath="c:\mylogs"/>
        <ns0:ExternalTool EnableTool="false"/>
    </ns0:Backend>
</ns0:App>
```

I need to modify values of attributes like MyDir1, MyDir2, EnableLogging, EnableTool in this xml file.

Googling helped me to get value from the attribute, but no luck in - how to modify attribute value or may be I am failing to use correct syntax.

Could anybody guide me in this ?

The code that I tried is as below:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
using namespace boost::property_tree;

int main()
{
    std::string xml_original = "C:\\temp\\config.xml";
    std::string xml_updated = "C:\\temp\\config_updated.xml";

    ptree tree;
    read_xml(sysCfg, tree);

    std::cout<<"old value: " << tree.get<std::string>("App.<xmlattr>.MyDir1");
    tree.put("App.<xmlattr>.MyDir1", "newPath");

    xml_writer_settings<char> w(' ', 4);
    write_xml(xml_updated, tree, std::locale(), w);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the namespace. I also used `std::string` for the `xml_writer_settings`:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::property_tree;

int main()
{
    std::string xml_original = "config.xml";
    std::string xml_updated = "config_updated.xml";

    ptree tree;
    read_xml(xml_original, tree);

    // must include the ns0 namespace
    std::cout << "old value: " << tree.get<std::string>("ns0:App.<xmlattr>.MyDir1");
    tree.put("ns0:App.<xmlattr>.MyDir1", "newPath");

    xml_writer_settings<std::string> w(' ', 4);
    write_xml(xml_updated, tree, std::locale(), w);
}
```

Comment: tree.put("ns0:App.<xmlattr>.MyDir1", "newPath"); It worked for me, Thanks for the help :)   But, xml_writer_settings<std::string> w(' ', 4);
    write_xml(xml_updated, tree, std::locale(), w); causing error : error C2664: 'boost::property_tree::xml_parser::write_xml' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_writer_settings<Ch>' to 'const boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_writer_settings<Ch> &' ,    but xml_writer_settings<char> w(' ', 4);  worked here

Comment: You're welcome. Good to hear it worked out in the end.